# Animation is not working on IE but it works in four browsers ( chrome, MOZ, O and Safari)

Tags: html, css

I need help on css, Im creating meteor shower animation and Ive got this code from other browser thru research. The meteor shower is not showing up on IE but It works fine on my four browser. I tried to put -ms-animation, (-ms-) for IE but it wont help. Help me to analyze my code.

```
.asteroid{
   position:absolute;
   top:-200px;
   left:-200px;
   width:200px;
   height:100px;
   opacity:0.9;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=90)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=90);
   -webkit-animation: asteroidAnimation 6s infinite;
   animation: asteroidAnimation 6s infinite;
  -ms-animation: asteroidAnimation 6s infinite;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
   -moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
   -ms-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
   -o-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
   animation-timing-function:ease-in;

   -webkit-animation-delay:2s;
   -moz-animation-delay:2s;
   -ms-animation-delay:2s;
   -o-animation-delay:2s;
   animation-delay:2s;
}
.asteroid-head{
   width:20px;
   height:10px;
   -webkit-border-radius:70%;
   -moz-border-radius:70%;
   border-radius:70%;
   background:#fff;
   -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 2px #c91515;
   -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 2px #c91515;
   box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 2px #c91515;
   position: absolute;
   bottom:0;
   right:-5px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(48deg);
   -moz-transform:rotate(48deg);
   -o-transform:rotate(48deg);
   -ms-transform:rotate(48deg);
   transform:rotate(48deg);
}
.asteroid-tail{
   width:0;
   height:0;
   border-left: 3px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 200px solid #fff;
   border-right: 3px solid transparent;
   position: absolute;
   bottom:-22px;
   right:75px;
   -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
   -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
   -o-transform:rotate(-45deg);
   -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
   transform:rotate(-45deg);
}


.a2{
   top:-205px;
   left:400px;
      -webkit-animation: asteroidAnimationTwo 8s infinite;
       animation: asteroidAnimationTwo 8s infinite;
           -ms-animation: asteroidAnimationTwo 8s infinite;

   -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
-moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
-ms-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
-o-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
animation-timing-function:ease-in;

-webkit-animation-delay:4s;
-moz-animation-delay:4s;
-ms-animation-delay:4s;
-o-animation-delay:4s;
animation-delay:4s;

}
.a3{
   top:-205px;
  left:-200px;
      -webkit-animation: asteroidAnimationThree 6s infinite;
      animation: asteroidAnimationThree 6s infinite;
     -ms-animation: asteroidAnimationTwo 8s infinite;

   -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
-moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
-ms-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
-o-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
animation-timing-function:ease-in;

-webkit-animation-delay:6s;
-moz-animation-delay:6s;
-ms-animation-delay:6s;
-o-animation-delay:6s;
animation-delay:6s;

}

.a4{
   top:-205px;
   left:-200px;
      -webkit-animation: asteroidAnimationFour 8s infinite;
       animation: asteroidAnimationFour 8s infinite;
     -ms-animation: asteroidAnimationFour 8s infinite;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
-moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
-ms-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
-o-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
animation-timing-function:ease-in;

-webkit-animation-delay:8s;
-moz-animation-delay:8s;
-ms-animation-delay:8s;
-o-animation-delay:8s;
animation-delay:8s;

}



/*--------------------------------------------------*/
@keyframes "asteroidAnimation" {
 0% {
    top: -200px;
      left: -200px;
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
      opacity: 0.8;
 }
 10% {
    top: 200px;
      left: 200px;
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
      opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
      opacity: 0;
 }

}

@-moz-keyframes asteroidAnimation {
 0% {
   top: -200px;
   left: -200px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=80);
   opacity: 0.8;
 }
 10% {
   top: 200px;
   left: 200px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }

}

@-webkit-keyframes "asteroidAnimation" {
 0% {
   top: -200px;
   left: -200px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=80);
   opacity: 0.8;
 }
 10% {
   top: 200px;
   left: 200px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }

}



@-o-keyframes "asteroidAnimation" {
 0% {
   top: -200px;
   left: -200px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=80);
   opacity: 0.8;
 }
 10% {
   top: 200px;
   left: 200px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }

}


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@keyframes "asteroidAnimationTwo" {
 0% {
    top: -200px;
      left: 400px;
       -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
      opacity: 0.8;
 }
 10% {
    top: 400px;
      left: 980px;
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
      opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
      opacity: 0;
 }

}

@-moz-keyframes asteroidAnimationTwo {
 0% {
   top: -200px;
   left: 400px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=80);
   opacity: 0.8;
 }
 10% {
   top: 400px;
   left: 980px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }

}

@-webkit-keyframes "asteroidAnimationTwo" {
 0% {
   top: -200px;
   left: 400px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=80);
   opacity: 0.8;
 }
 10% {
   top: 400px;
   left: 980px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }

}



@-o-keyframes "asteroidAnimationTwo" {
 0% {
   top: -200px;
   left: 400px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=80);
   opacity: 0.8;
 }
 10% {
   top: 400px;
   left: 980px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }

}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@keyframes "asteroidAnimationThree" {
 0% {
    top: -200px;
      left: 300px;
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
      opacity: 0.8;
 }
 10% {
    top: 300px;
      left: 880px;
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
      opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
      opacity: 0;
 }

}

@-moz-keyframes asteroidAnimationThree {
 0% {
   top: -200px;
   left: 300px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=80);
   opacity: 0.8;
 }
 10% {
   top: 300px;
   left: 880px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }

}

@-webkit-keyframes "asteroidAnimationThree" {
 0% {
   top: -200px;
   left: 300px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=80);
   opacity: 0.8;
 }
 10% {
   top: 300px;
   left: 880px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }

}



@-o-keyframes "asteroidAnimationThree" {
 0% {
   top: -200px;
   left: 300px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=80);
   opacity: 0.8;
 }
 10% {
   top: 300px;
   left: 880px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }

}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@keyframes "asteroidAnimationFour" {
 0% {
    top: -200px;
      left: 500px;
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
      opacity: 0.8;
 }
 10% {
    top: 500px;
      left: 1080px;
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
      opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
      opacity: 0;
 }

}

@-moz-keyframes asteroidAnimationFour {
 0% {
   top: -200px;
   left: 500px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=80);
   opacity: 0.8;
 }
 10% {
   top: 500px;
   left: 1080px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }

}

@-webkit-keyframes "asteroidAnimationFour" {
 0% {
   top: -200px;
   left: 500px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=80);
   opacity: 0.8;
 }
 10% {
   top: 500px;
   left: 1080px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }

}



@-o-keyframes "asteroidAnimationFour" {
 0% {
   top: -200px;
   left: 500px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=80);
   opacity: 0.8;
 }
 10% {
   top: 500px;
   left: 1080px;
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }

}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

<div class="asteroid">
        <div class="asteroid-head"></div>
        <div class="asteroid-tail"></div>
    </div>

<div class="asteroid a2">
        <div class="asteroid-head"></div>
        <div class="asteroid-tail"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: "code from other browser thru research" - please share source. Which version of IE are you talking about? Did you google browser compatibility? -> "browser compatibility animation css"

Comment: thru codepen from anon. Im using ie 11 broswer and css/css3 for html code. I think it should work on any browser.

Comment: If you have a look at [caniuse.com/css-animation](http://caniuse.com/css-animation), you see that animations were only partially supported in IE up to 9.0. In IE10 and up it should be no problem. (as you found yourself, meanwhile ...) - And thanks for codepen!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I write it in the answer.
In my project, I had to specify the MIME to IE to let the CSS work. And I read that this is a "security system" required by IE.
Try this solution, I think it will work.

```
String typeMIME(String file) {
  int n = file.lastIndexOf('.');
  if (n >= 0) {
    String extension = file.substring(n);
    String returnMIME = "";
    switch (extension) {
      case '.html':
        returnMIME = 'text/html';
        break;
      case '.js':
        returnMIME = 'application/x-javascript';
        break;
      case '.css':
        returnMIME = 'text/css';
        break;
      case '.dart':
        returnMIME = 'application/dart';
        break;
      case '.ico':
        returnMIME = 'image/x-icon';
        break;
      case '.png':
        returnMIME = 'image/png';
        break;
      case '.gif':
        returnMIME = 'image/gif';
        break;
    }
    return returnMIME;
  }
  return 'text/plain';
}
```

You need specifically the part:

```
case '.css':
  returnMIME = 'text/css';
  break;
```

But this function I di is written into server-side code, to accept the webpage-request.
I hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.. I just omitted the double "" on keyframes and it works.But I will also try your code. :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well my code is for server-side so it may won't help. :)